# how can I indent a paragraph of plain text in emacs org-mode?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

How can I indent a paragraph of plain text in emacs org-mode? The paragraph doesn't have any bullets or stars and is free standing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Select the paragraph and use `C-x C-i` (i.e. `indent-rigidly`) probably with a numeric prefix argument to say how many columns to indent (or use `C-x C-i C-x z z z z ...` until it's where you want it to be.

Comment: Thank you for your very useful answer. When you do C-x C-i C-x z, is there another key that would reverse that for when if I indent too much and I want to pull it back?

Comment: The regular `undo` works to reverse it step-by-step for me. Also note that if you're commonly indenting by 4 characters, `C-u C-x C-i` is particularly easy to type.

Comment: Oh, and in Emacs 24.4, the interactive behaviour of `C-x C-i` will have changed such that (unless you pass a prefix argument) you type it once and then use the left and right arrows to increase and decrease the indentation until you're happy. You might find that convenient.

Comment: `C-x TAB` is a modern default key binding for `indent-rigidly`.

Comment: That's a useful comment, but note that `TAB` and `C-i` are the exact same thing (ascii 9), so `C-x TAB` is precisely as modern and default as `C-x C-i` is.  Users can choose their preferred way of typing it.

Answer (score 0):

There may exist more elegant solutions, but an #+begin/end_example block should work (it will be translated as PRE in HTML).